# Why WebGL slower than Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am just started to play around with canvas and webgl, read some article, etc.. and as per my knowledge, WebGL should be much more faster than canvas, but in these following tests it is remarkably slower:

- http://jsperf.com/canvas-drawimage-vs-webgl-drawarrays
- http://jsperf.com/three-js-canvas-vs-webgl/2

I run them in Chrome and Firefox, in both browser the difference was around 80% percent.

Why does canvas render faster? Is jsperf inaccurate? Did canvas become much more optimized in browsers?

(PS: I am not the author of the tests, I just found them.)

Comment: To me the first test ended with WebGL being faster on Chrome. I think it's just a matter of the task at hand, one does it better than the other.

Comment: Hmm interesting, for me the advantage of the canvas is always between 50-80%. What could cause a such big difference?

Comment: Different browser implementations and the capacity of the PC's graphics card play a big role here in my opinion.

Comment: I ran it on Chrome too. I have a high-end laptop, but it should not matter  anyway because the hardware only should change the raw amount of the draws, not the ratio between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that webgl/opengl is not meant for drawing a SINGLE quad at a time. GPUs are designed to be massively parallel and thus to gain the most out of webgl you have to draw in batches.

You should be comparing drawing 10k images in canvas versus drawing 10k images in webgl using an appropriate webgl implementation. Most of the webgl libs you find, however, are written for the convenience for the client but not necessarily for max performance.

My implementation of 2d webgl renderer is much faster than canvas (100 times+), particularly if you need to rotate/scale the images. And of course, if you need your own blending operations, then webgl is the only way to go.

Comment: Is your implementation opensource?

Comment: Unfortunately no and the code is still mostly for internal use (its a mess)